# navbar-brand is not changing the color in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the color of the `navbar-brand` class using Bootstrap 4 but somehow it won't change. I tried to read the documentation but still couldn't find why it's not working. i have added a navbar-custom class to target the navbar-band class.

my code:

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
  .navbar-custom {
    background-color: #ff5a5f;
  }
  /* change the brand and text color */
  .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  /* change the link color */
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>iGloo</title>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/bf64aa8e30.js"></script>
</head>




<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-custom">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">iGloo</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <img src="https://cdn.homedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/room-for-teens-girl-orange-picture.jpg" , class="img-fluid" alt="Room Image"></img>
      </div>
    </div><br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 title">
        <h2>A House in the Middle of South Avenues.</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5>Ahmed Fahad</h5>
      </div>
    </div><br>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">

          <i class="fa fa-bed fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"><p>Bedrooms 3 </p></i>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <i class="fa fa-bath fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"><p> Bathrooms 3 </p></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"><p>People 6</p></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"><p>Entire House</p></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <h3>About this House</h3>
        <p>A wonderful house in the middle of South Avenues. It's good for a fmaily who are looking for a holiday in South Avenues. It has alot of windows and the sun light is perfect in the house.</p>
      </div>
    </div><br>
    <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <h3>Amenities</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">

          <i class="fa fa-wifi fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"><p>Wifi</p></i>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <i class="fa fa-television fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"><p>TV</p></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <i class="fa fa-bed fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"><p>6 Beds</p></i>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>



</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the problem still going I think should call your custom css after calling bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 3):

```css
.navbar-brand{
    color:red !important;
  }
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 2):

I work with asp.net core 2.2, have just updated from Bootstrap 3.3.7 to 4.3.1 and now try to bring my layout to work again...
I also have this problem (and various further... :-)
The navbar-brand should be grey per default in my case and then change to white if hoovered. After the update, it was always showed white (hoover don't work).
To set the colors explicitly in bootstrap.css has not worked.
The only (not nice) workaround in my case was to set the style with **!important** **before** the navbar is created (in my case in _Layout.cshtml as I work with asp.net core 2.2).

```
 <style type="text/css">
.navbar-brand {
  color: #9d9d9d !important; 
}
.navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-brand:focus {
color: #fff  !important;
}
```

It now seems to work in my case...
Note:
If the style is placed, after the navbar is created, the style take place, but the color is set to white (and then back to gray) as soon as another menu item is selected.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
    your snippet here
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add an additional class name "brand":**

```
    <a class="navbar-brand brand" href="#">iGloo</a>
```

**CSS should look like this:**

```
    .navbar-brand.brand {
       color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your CSS for `*` and that is causing the CSS below it to not be applied.  Correcting this causes your color alterations to apply as expected.

Comment: i did but still it won't change

Comment: Make sure your path to `main.css` is valid then; because the edited code you've provided makes `iGloo` white until you hover over it.

Answer (score 0):

### You can give a try by defining a custom class over navbar-brand

For example-

```
<a class="navbar-brand custom" href="#">iGloo</a>

.navbar-brand.custom{
  color:blue
}
```

Comment: This css you should define after your bootstrap.min.css. [AHmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5178670/ahmed)

Answer (score 0):

You must've figured it out by now since the question was asked quite a while ago. By the way I just came up with this issue and none of the above mentioned answered worked. The issue is with the theme we're using. In the above question youve used .navbar-light theme. so you cant actually access that with a custom class. So simply access through the theme class.

```
.<your theme class> .navbar-brand{

}
```

So your css would be

```
.navbar-light .navbar-brand{
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was defining it with an id. Since id is more specific and ranks higher than classes, it will work. Try that and you will get it.

First, create a custom css file. (link it to your html)
In that css, add the id and make sure in the 'a' tag, you add the id before the class.